# Can I use nor in this example:

Tags: or-nor

I haven't eaten rice nor potatoes. 
I looked up that nor is usually followed by neither on this site: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-use-nor
However, I would like to know if the way I used it in the example is correct to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `not ... nor` - so no, it is incorrect.

> I have eaten neither rice nor potatoes.

is the correct usage

If you insist on using not, you need two sentences:

> I haven't eaten rice, nor have I eaten potatoes.

Comment: How about "I haven't eaten rice or potatoes."?

Comment: OP was asking about `nor` - I have to admit I would expect your version to be ok - at least in spoken conversation